# Error instalación proyecto laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ubuntu, composer

Cuando trato de instalar un proyecto nuevo en mi carpeta llamando a `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel miProyecto` me sale el siguiente error:

```
    @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mbstring.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mbstring.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.5.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.4.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.4.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.4.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.4.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.4.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.3.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.3.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.2.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.2.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.2.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.2.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.2.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.1.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.1.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.1.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.1.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.1.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.9 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.8 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.13 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.12 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.11 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.10 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - phpunit/phpunit 6.0.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit ~6.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[6.0.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.10, 6.0.11, 6.0.12, 6.0.13, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.8, 6.0.9, 6.1.0, 6.1.1, 6.1.2, 6.1.3, 6.1.4, 6.2.0, 6.2.1, 6.2.2, 6.2.3, 6.2.4, 6.3.0, 6.3.1, 6.4.0, 6.4.1, 6.4.2, 6.4.3, 6.4.4, 6.5.0, 6.5.1, 6.5.2, 6.5.3, 6.5.4, 6.5.5, 6.5.6, 6.5.7].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Estoy usando Ubuntu 16.04 y tengo instalado xampp o debería decir, lamp y por tanto php y composer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No tienes instalada la extensión `ext-dom`, la puedes instalar con las siguientes dos líneas:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml
```

`php7.1-xml` tiene todos los paquetes necesarios.

Comment: Gracias, justo los he instalado y funciona!